# How to replace $followed by a word with a string in groovy

Tags: groovy

Input string is

```
SELECT A.XYZ
, CASE
WHEN $greatestStart > $aggLocal
THEN from_tz(CAST(to_date($greatestStart) AS TIMESTAMP), INTZ.ABC) AT TIME ZONE (:standardtz)
ELSE from_tz(cast(to_date($aggStd) as TIMESTAMP), (:standardInstallTimeZone)) AT TIME ZONE (:standardtz)
END START_DTTM
......
```

I need to replace `$greatestStart` with a string in groovy. Can some one provide me inputs please ?

When i have like this

```
String pattern = "(\\$greatestStart)*?"
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m11 = pattern1.matcher(sql);

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup 
failed:
D1_AGGMCSQL: 111: [Static type checking] - The variable [greatestStart] is 
undeclared.
 @ line 111, column 34.
              String pattern = "(\\$greatestStart)*?"
                                ^
D1_AGGMCSQL: 112: [Static type checking] - The variable [greatestStart] is 
undeclared.
@ line 112, column 101.
IE.INSTALL_EVT_ID, CASE WHEN $greatestSt
                             ^
D1_AGGMCSQL: 112: [Static type checking] - The variable 
[aggLocal] is undeclared.
@ line 112, column 118.
, CASE WHEN $greatestStart > $aggLocal
                             ^
enter code here
3 errors
```

Comment: first your problem that the string `"hello $name"` in groovy expects `name` variable to be declared...

Comment: Try using single quotes around your pattern

Comment: Why not use parameters for your SQL statement instead?  You're opening yourself up to SQL injection problems if you're just replacing parts of a query with arbitrary text.